# can visual studio code return me to editor after searching, without hitting ESCAPE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCode configured to not search for text until I hit ENTER.  But after I pull up search dialog, type text and hit ENTER, I have to hit ESCAPE to exit the search dialog.

Is there a way to disable that so after hitting ENTER, I am back to the editor without hitting ESCAPE?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is to "overload" the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to do two things: (1) go to the next find match and (2) refocus the editor.  For that you would need a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) for example to run two commands in sequence.

In your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
      "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
    ]
  },
  "when": "findInputFocussed"
}
```

This works in my testing.